# why default wordpress loop not working outside index.php

Tags: wp-query, loop

I tried the basic wordpress loop ([Default WordPress Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop))

```
 <?php 
// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<!-- the loop -->
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<!-- end of the loop -->

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

if this code in index.php, it works fine. but if I copied  it to another page like `www.mysite.com/test` it prints

> Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.

What should I do?

Comment: Is the above your entire "test" file?

Comment: Did you copy the $args? Is it in a template file, and is your test page using that template file?

Comment: `$atts = array( 'post_type' =>  'post' );`
when I run (($GLOBALS['wp_query']->request)) the result is `SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND (wp_posts.ID = '34') AND wp_posts.post_type = 'page'  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC `